# Using package appendix with llncs

Tags: appendices, lncs

I'm trying to get appendices to work with llncs as my document class.

This minimal example does not work (i.e. complains about \@chapapp being undefined). Changing llncs to article fixes this (I guess the package figures out that article does not have chapters).

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Also you should know this}
Really.
\section{And I also came across this}
But I need to put this in an appendix so that my paper is not too long.
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Using the `subappendices` environment compiles but prints "Appendix 0.A"... I guess I'm fine with using subappendices, but I need a way to get rid of that 0.

So which should it be? Subappendices (not that weird since llncs, like article, only goes up to sections) and removing the leading 0. somehow (bonus points for that), or telling the package that it somehow should number with sections instead of chapters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know whether the OP meant something like this, but this removes the leading zero and compiles.

`appendix` package seems to expect `\@chapapp` which basically should be there, even for `llncs.cls`.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}


\title{A very sophisticated document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{subappendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%
% or try \arabic{section}

\section{Also you should know this}
Really.
\section{And I also came across this}
But I need to put this in an appendix so that my paper is not too long.
\end{subappendices}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Version works with `\relax`ed `\@chapapp`, now `\begin{appendices}...etc` work as expected.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@chapapp}{\relax}%
\makeatother

\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,header]{appendix}



\title{A Very Sophisticated Document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Other Content}

\begin{subappendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%
% or try \arabic{section}

\section{Also you should know this}
Really.
\section{And I also came across this}
But I need to put this in an appendix so that my paper is not too long.
\end{subappendices}


\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\appendixname~\Alph{section}}
\section{Also you should know this}
Really.
\section{And I also came across this}
But I need to put this in an appendix so that my paper is not too long.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

**Note: I did not update the screen shot, it does not show essentially new output.**

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I want to get. What I meant to say was that using the `appendices` environment works with the `article` document class, but not with `llncs`. So somehow `article` informs the appendix package that its highest level is `section`, while `llncs` doesn't so the package is confused because it expects chapters...? I have no idea if that makes sense, but I don't know enough about the inner workings of the appendix package.

What's sure is that `\begin{appendices}` works with article but not with llncs, which fails saying `\@chapapp undefined`.

Comment: @Peniblec: Nice that it works, but I am sure, there is a way to disable the error too

Comment: This didn't work for me; but when I replaced `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}` with `\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Alph{section}}
 \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}`, it worked.